# Use .jsp as rest url which does not look for JSP file

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am trying to use document.jsp as REST URL but it is looking for .jsp file instead.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/document.jsp", params = { "doc"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
String fetchDocContent(@RequestParam(value = "doc") String doc) {
    String Code=doc.substring(doc.lastIndexOf("/"), doc.lastIndexOf("."));
    return code;
}
```

URL is:

```
   http://localhost:8080/MyProject/document.jsp?DOC=XML/11791.xml
```

There is no document.jsp in my application. I am creating this Rest url for contents of old application which has links like

`<a class="blink"  href="document.jsp?DOC=XML/11791.xml">Cr</a>`

in many places. Now I am trying to reuse the same url. Kindly advise.

Comment: It's not so clear what you are asking ?

Comment: Try move your document.jsp from webapps folder to inside WEB-INF folder. Or remove .jsp from the url and from requestmapping

Comment: there is no document.jsp in my application. I am creating this Rest url for contents of old application which has links like  <a class="blink"  href="document.jsp?DOC=XML/11791.xml">Cr</a>  in many places. Now I am trying to use same url.